# How to get access to rabbitmq console on cloudfoundry.com?

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I want to be able to manage my RabbitMQ queues and exchanges for my app that is deployed on cloudfoundry.  I have caldecott installed and can tunnel to look at mySql and mongodb, but I can't access the management console for my RabbitMQ services. [this](http://joe.blog.freemansoft.com/2011/11/accessing-rabbitmq-console-in-cloud.html) site describes how to do it for a micro cloud, but it doesn't apply to a deployed app on cloudfoundry.com.

I can tunnel to the RabbitMQ service, but can't find an app to use the connection.  I've tried to use a browser on the connection since the RabbitMQ console is http based, but this didn't work.  The connection info is a bit more involved than a port number.  It has a username, password, name, pass, and vhost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, there is no HTTP access to RabbitMQ running on CloudFoundry.com, and you cannot connect using any other clients that I know of via a caldecott tunnel - the admin plugin information is not available outside of CloudFoundry.com itself, so it is impossible to find the user and port for a connection. It would be great if you could open an issue in JIRA (https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa) to make the engineering team aware that this is an issue for you.